# When receiving message MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

**UPDATE:**
After moving fromTcp() from the holder class to the endpoint class it all worked well again, now I'm baffled why it even works now because for me it makes no sense for why it works

After some headhaches and searching in all stackoverflow i have a dispatcher has no suscriber when i recieve a message from the server, but not when i send a response back where everything works fine.

connection generator :

```
@Service
@EnableIntegration
public class TcpConnectionsHolder {


@Autowired
private IntegrationFlowContext flowContext;


/**
 * Definition of flow channels
 * 
 * @return MessageChannel
 */
@Bean
public MessageChannel fromTcp() {
    final DirectChannel channel = new DirectChannel();
    channel.addInterceptor(new ChannelInterceptorAdapter() {
        @Override
        public Message<?> preSend(final Message<?> message, final MessageChannel channel) {
            // Parse Message byte[] to StringHex
            final byte[] bMessagePayload = (byte[]) message.getPayload();
            return MessageBuilder.withPayload(Hex.encodeHexString(bMessagePayload))
                    .copyHeaders(message.getHeaders()).build();
        }
    });
    return channel;
}

private final LinkedHashMap<String, TcpNetClientConnectionFactory> clientConnect =
        new LinkedHashMap<String, TcpNetClientConnectionFactory>();

private final LinkedHashMap<String, TcpReceivingChannelAdapter> reciverAdapter =
        new LinkedHashMap<String, TcpReceivingChannelAdapter>();

private final LinkedHashMap<String, MessageChannel> sendingAdpater =
        new LinkedHashMap<String, MessageChannel>();

public MessageChannel getMessageChannel(String host, int port) {
    return sendingAdpater.get(host+port);
}


public TcpReceivingChannelAdapter getReceiverChannel(String host, int port) {
    return reciverAdapter.get(host+port);
}

private TcpNetClientConnectionFactory getclientConnectionFactory(String host, int port,int headBytes) {

    TcpNetClientConnectionFactory cf = clientConnect.get(host+port);
    if(cf==null) {
        cf = new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory(host, port);
        final ByteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer by = new ByteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer(headBytes);
        cf.setSingleUse(false);
        cf.setSoKeepAlive(true);
        cf.setSerializer(by);
        cf.setDeserializer(by);
        clientConnect.put(host+port,cf);
    }
    return cf;
}
public TcpReceivingChannelAdapter addReceiverChannel(String host, int port) {
    return addReceiverChannel(host,port,2,2000);
}
public TcpReceivingChannelAdapter addReceiverChannel(String host, int port,int headBytes,int retryInterval) {
    TcpReceivingChannelAdapter adapter = new TcpReceivingChannelAdapter();
    TcpNetClientConnectionFactory cf = getclientConnectionFactory(host,port,headBytes);
    adapter.setConnectionFactory(cf);
    adapter.setClientMode(true);
    adapter.setErrorChannelName("errorChannel");
    adapter.setRetryInterval(retryInterval);
    adapter.setOutputChannel(fromTcp());

    IntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows.from(adapter).get();

    this.flowContext.registration(flow).id(host+port + ".in").addBean(cf).register();

    this.reciverAdapter.put(host+port, adapter);

    return adapter;
}

public MessageChannel addSendingChannel(String host, int port) {
    return addSendingChannel(host,port,2);
}

public MessageChannel addSendingChannel(String host, int port,int headBytes) {
       TcpSendingMessageHandler sender = new TcpSendingMessageHandler();
       sender.setConnectionFactory(getclientConnectionFactory(host,port,headBytes));

        IntegrationFlow flow = f -> f.handle(sender);

        IntegrationFlowRegistration flowRegistration =
                this.flowContext.registration(flow).id(host+port + ".out").register();

        MessageChannel inputChannel = flowRegistration.getInputChannel();
        this.sendingAdpater.put(host+port, inputChannel);
        return inputChannel;
}

public void removeReceiverChannel(String host, int port) {
    this.reciverAdapter.remove(host+port);
    this.flowContext.remove(host+port + ".in");
}

public void removeSendingChannel(String host, int port) {
    this.sendingAdpater.remove(host+port);
    this.flowContext.remove(host+port + ".out");
}

}
```

an message endpoint:

```
@Configuration
@MessageEndpoint
public class BridgeMessageEndpoint {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BridgeMessageEndpoint.class);

@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "fromTcp")
public void outbound(final String inMessage, final @Headers Map<String, Object> headerMap) {
    sendToApi(inMessage, headerMap);
}

private void sendToApi(final String inMessage, final Map<String, Object> headerMap) {
    LOGGER.debug("Recuperando el mensaje Hex {}", inMessage);
    final PaymentOrder paymentOrder = new PaymentOrder();
    paymentOrder.setMessage(inMessage);
    final SplitterRestClient splitterRestClient = applicationContext.getBean(SplitterRestClient.class);
    splitterRestClient.reportPayment(paymentOrder, headerMap);
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "errorChannel")
public MessageHandler logger() {
    final LoggingHandler loggingHandler = new LoggingHandler(LoggingHandler.Level.DEBUG.name());
    loggingHandler.setLoggerName("Log");
    return loggingHandler;
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow toTcp() {
    return f -> f.route(new TcpRouter());
}

}
```

and then the initiation of the holder:

```
@Component
public class TcpConnectionsController implements CommandLineRunner{

@Autowired
private TcpConnectionsHolder holder;

@Autowired
private ListNodeConfig listNodes;

@Value("${socket.tcp.headBytes}")
private int headBytes;

@Value("${socket.tcp.retryInterval}")
private int retryInterval;

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

    for(Node node:listNodes.getNodes()) {
        holder.addReceiverChannel(node.getIp(), node.getPort(),headBytes,retryInterval);
        holder.addSendingChannel(node.getIp(), node.getPort(),headBytes);
    }

}

}
```

I know the problem is in fromTcp() but as much as I search, I am unable to see where the problem or error lies.

**EDIT**
Complete stacktrace:

```
[INFO  ] (DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:343) org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor : Starting beans in phase 2147483647
2018/06/22 13:56:47,454 [INFO  ] (DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:151) springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper : Context refreshed
2018/06/22 13:56:47,504 [INFO  ] (DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:154) springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper : Found 1 custom documentation plugin(s)
2018/06/22 13:56:47,555 [INFO  ] (ApiListingReferenceScanner.java:41) springfox.documentation.spring.web.scanners.ApiListingReferenceScanner : Scanning for api listing references
2018/06/22 13:56:47,826 [INFO  ] (DirectJDKLog.java:180) org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol : Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
2018/06/22 13:56:47,827 [INFO  ] (DirectJDKLog.java:180) org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol : Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
2018/06/22 13:56:47,829 [INFO  ] (DirectJDKLog.java:180) org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool : Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
2018/06/22 13:56:47,836 [INFO  ] (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:201) org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2018/06/22 13:56:47,902 [INFO  ] (AbstractConnectionFactory.java:481) org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetClientConnectionFactory : started 180.112.19.1153115.inorg.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetClientConnectionFactory#0, host=180.112.19.115, port=3115
2018/06/22 13:56:47,922 [INFO  ] (AbstractEndpoint.java:120) org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpReceivingChannelAdapter : started org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpReceivingChannelAdapter#0
2018/06/22 13:56:47,949 [INFO  ] (EventDrivenConsumer.java:108) org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer : Adding {ip:tcp-outbound-channel-adapter} as a subscriber to the '180.112.19.1153115.out.input' channel
2018/06/22 13:56:47,950 [INFO  ] (AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:81) org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel : Channel 'ck-da-bridge:local:8080.180.112.19.1153115.out.input' has 1 subscriber(s).
2018/06/22 13:56:47,950 [INFO  ] (AbstractConnectionFactory.java:481) org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetClientConnectionFactory : started 180.112.19.1153115.inorg.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetClientConnectionFactory#0, host=180.112.19.115, port=3115
2018/06/22 13:56:47,950 [INFO  ] (AbstractEndpoint.java:120) org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer : started org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#1
2018/06/22 13:56:47,953 [INFO  ] (StartupInfoLogger.java:57) com.santander.ck.bridge.spring.Application : Started Application in 13.078 seconds (JVM running for 14.159)
2018/06/22 13:57:01,164 [ERROR ] (LoggingHandler.java:192) org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler : org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'ck-da-bridge:local:8080.180.112.19.1153115.in.channel#0'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=f0f8f0f0c2200000800000020400000000000000f0f5f9f9f1f0f3f0f6f2f2f1f3f5f6f5f5f0f0f0f0f1f2f0f6f0f2f2f0f2f0f0f0f9d4c3c3f0f1f1f1e3f0f0f8f2, headers={ip_tcp_remotePort=3115, ip_connectionId=amm012059amm.scisb.isban.corp:3115:53402:3722e84f-49ce-4e77-a4a1-6e82cefe58b4, ip_localInetAddress=/180.101.130.119, ip_address=180.112.19.115, id=2c6e2e09-9faa-a56e-3921-edf7a03a9a3c, ip_hostname=amm012059amm.scisb.isban.corp, timestamp=1529668621142}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=f0f000022f0f6e3f0f0f8f2, headers={ip_tcp_remotePort=3115, ip_connectionId=amm012059amm.scisb.isban.corp:3115:53402:3722e84f-49ce-4e77-a4a1-6e82cefe58b4, ip_localInetAddress=/180.101.130.119, ip_address=180.112.19.115, id=2c6e2e09-9faa-a56e-3921-edf7a03a9a3c, ip_hostname=amm012059amm.scisb.isban.corp, timestamp=1529668621142}]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:93)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:425)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:375)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:188)
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpReceivingChannelAdapter.onMessage(TcpReceivingChannelAdapter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection.run(TcpNetConnection.java:182)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=f0f8f0f0c2200000800000020400000000000000f0f5f9f9f1f0f3f0f6f2f2f1f3f5f6f5f5f0f0f0f0f1f2f0f6f0f2f2f0f2f0f0f0f9d4c3c3f0f1f1f1e3f0f0f8f2, headers={ip_tcp_remotePort=3115, ip_connectionId=amm012059amm.scisb.isban.corp:3115:53402:3722e84f-49ce-4e77-a4a1-6e82cefe58b4, ip_localInetAddress=/180.101.130.119, ip_address=180.112.19.115, id=2c6e2e09-9faa-a56e-3921-edf7a03a9a3c, ip_hostname=amm012059amm.scisb.isban.corp, timestamp=1529668621142}]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:154)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:89)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: More stack trace, please? Any chances that you can share a simple project on GitHub to let us to play with?

Comment: @Artem Bilan,Aded complete stacktrace. I can't put a github project, i don't have full control of everything

Comment: Can you determine what is `ck-da-bridge`? Can you turn on DEBUG logging level for `org.springframework.integration` category and trace how message travels?

Comment: OK. I would say that you don't show all the code on the matter. According the channel massage name `ck-da-bridge:local:8080.180.112.19.1153115.in.channel#0` you have something else in your `in` flow. Because it indeed shows that the problem is on the `TcpReceivingChannelAdapter.onMessage()`, but your flow is just shows such a `TcpReceivingChannelAdapter` is sending only to the `fromTcp()`.

Comment: What Spring Integration version do you use?

Comment: spring integration 4.3.x
ck-da-bridge is the name of the proyect/application.
yes TcpReceivingChannelAdapter is only sending to the fromTcp().
This is all the code its basicaly scattered classes that i have pieced together to make the connections dinamycally instead of it being 2 fixed connections

the rest of the code is basically behind another microservice and i don't end sending there because fromTcp returns the no dispatcher exception.

the outbund beand should be capturing fromTcp call and continue with the procesing

Comment: Se my answer: I suggested you to turn on Message History for better understanding, but looks like there is anything else not only just `IntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows.from(adapter).get();`. I mean according the stack trace you have some other endpoints configured in this flow...

Comment: Otherwise we can't help you without the code to let us to play.

Comment: The classes that i modified are the same that already existed and that i posted here. I'm a bit bound here because the company is really strict about making code avaiable and t was difficult to ask permision even to solve this.

But in the rest of the code there is no aparent @MessageEndpoint except the one I posted here. As i told we went from fixed 2 beans for conection and receiver to the integrationflow and thats the only place that channel.in is created. will try to pass more info or a working minimal copy into github

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn on DEBUG logging level for the `org.springframework.integration` category and trace how message travels.

Also there is a [Message History](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#message-history) pattern for you to track the message path in headers. This way you will be able to see what channels your messages has passed and where it is stuck with the `Dispatcher has no subscribers`.

Although you would need to restart a `MessageHistoryConfigurer` after each `IntegrationFlow` registration.

Feel free to raise a JIRA on the matter to let dynamic flows to be tracked by the Message History.

**UPDATE**

OK. Having your simple code like this:

```
TcpReceivingChannelAdapter adapter = new TcpReceivingChannelAdapter();
TcpNetClientConnectionFactory cf = getclientConnectionFactory(host,port,headBytes);
adapter.setConnectionFactory(cf);
adapter.setClientMode(true);
adapter.setErrorChannelName("errorChannel");
adapter.setRetryInterval(retryInterval);
adapter.setOutputChannel(fromTcp());

IntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows.from(adapter).get();
```

And the fact that there is no more components after this `handler` (adn stack trace really confirm that), I assume that you use some Spring Integration Java DSL version without the proper fix to extract an `outputChannel` from the provided `MessageProducer.getOutputChannel()`.

To fix that I suggest you to modify the code like this:

```
IntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows.from(adapter).channel(fromTcp()).get();
```

I mean move the channel reference from the `TcpReceivingChannelAdapter` definition to the flow. Or just try upgrade to the latest `1.2.3` version for the `spring-integration-java-dsl` dependency!

**UPDATE 2**

Another thought about the code we have so far.

You register a `TcpReceivingChannelAdapter` from the `CommandLineRunner`. This way the `IntegrationFlow` is started automatically and ready to receive data over TCP, but at the same time the `@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "fromTcp")` is not started yet to consume messages from the mentioned channel. That's how you get that `Dispatcher has no subscribers`. Or you should mar your `this.flowContext.registration(flow)` with the `autoStartup(false)` and let it to be started lately during the normal auto-startup phase, already together with the service activator. Or you should not use `CommandLineRunner` approach for such a logic: it is really too early from there to start some activity.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/rGFZz22c pastebin of the DEBUG, hope it can help a bit and looking into uploading the project to a public github

Comment: and this is the output withouth the TcpSendingMessageHandler flow active 

https://pastebin.com/8KqwAyFT

Comment: Well, you don’t show DEBUG I’ve requested and there is no Message History in your logs yet. There is some new `CANAL` note though- maybe this can help you somehow. I’m sorry, but we can’t help without minimal project to play: you definitely don’t show something else from your code...

Comment: The "CANAL" was a change in the inbound conector name.

I moved fromTcp() from TcpConnectionsHolder  to BridgeMessageEndpoint .

And now it works perfectly again, it doesn't send the Dispatcher has no subscribers, Does it mean it can now be seen by the service activator that is in the same class? or is it because the "fromTcp()" is now in the endpoint class?

Or should i better edit the question?

Comment: Please, find a UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Sadly this change doesn't let spring to start. as seen in this stacktrace https://pastebin.com/RjcCWMSZ

and sadly i can't change the version directly so i will raise an issue to update. Thank you

Comment: Right. That's what I mean that you have there something else and you don't show that. As I said before: we are unable to help without more context. That's really bad you can't share with us a simple project to reproduce.

Comment: See an UPDATE 2 in my answer.